# Show that $\lim_{x\to \alpha_{i}^{\pm}}\frac{p_n(x)}{p_{n+1}(x)}=\pm \infty$ where $p_n\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $p_n\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n$ *with positive leading coefficient*, having $n$ simple real roots. Let $\alpha_1<\dots <\alpha_{n+1}$ denote the real roots of $p_{n+1}$. If $p_n/p_{n+1}$ is strictly decreasing, why is it true that
$$
\lim_{x\to \alpha_{i}^{\pm}}\frac{p_n(x)}{p_{n+1}(x)}=\pm \infty
$$
for $i=1,\dots, n+1$?

**Edit**: *It is assumed that $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ have no common zeroes.*

Comment: The denominator converges to zero, and the numerator to a finite non-zero value. So the absolute value of quotient converges to $ \infty$. Now use that the quotient is decreasing.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, I think I get it with $\lim_{x\to \alpha_{i}^{\pm}}\left | \frac{p_n(x)}{p_{n+1}(x)} \right |= \infty$, but not with the monotonicity part ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a root of $p_{n+1}$. Then $p_n(a) \ne 0 = p_{n+1}(a)$, so that $\lim_{x\to a}\left | \frac{p_n(x)}{p_{n+1}(x)} \right |= \infty$.

Therefore it suffices to prove the following:

> Let $f:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ be a decreasing function.
>
> - If $\lim_{x \to a^+} |f(x)| = \infty $ then $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = +\infty $.
> - If $\lim_{x \to b^-} |f(x)| = \infty $ then $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = -\infty $.

Here it suffices to prove the first part, the second part works in the same way. The *idea* is that $f$ cannot approach $-\infty$ for $x$ close to $a$ since it is decreasing, therefore it must approach $+\infty$. A formal proof could look like this:

Let $c = (a+b)/2$ and $K_0 = |f(c)|$. Then
$$ \tag{*}
 f(x) \ge f(c) \ge -|f(c)| = -K_0
$$
for $a < x \le c$.

We have $\lim_{x \to a^+} |f(x)| = \infty $, so for all $K > K_0$ there is  a $\delta \in (0, c-a)$ such that for all $x \in (a, a + \delta)$:
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(x)| > K &\iff \left( f(x) < -K \text{ or } f(x) > K\right) \\
&\implies f(x) > K 
\end{align}
$$
where the last implication holds because $f(x) < -K$ is not possible, according to $(*)$.

This proves that $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = +\infty$.